How to stop Xamarin iOS crashing when turning on or off Bluetooth speaker?
I've created a AVAudioSession as per the code below in my Xamarin Forms iOS app.
I then create an AVAudioEngine with a AVAudioPlayerNode that successfully plays an AVAudioFile on the iPhone built-in speaker.
However, when I turn on my Bluetooth speaker the app freezes and doesn't recover.
If the Bluetooth speaker is connected before I play the AVAudioFile, it likewise plays successfully over Bluetooth, but freezes if I turn Bluetooth off.
I was hoping I could detect the RouteChanged event when the Bluetooth turns on or off, and stop my audio playback thus possibly preventing a crash, but this event for some reason only fires when the category is changed.
Three questions:

Why isn't RouteChanged being called on the Bluetooth event?

Shouldn't the iPhone re-route the audio automatically between built-in speaker and Bluetooth when the Bluetooth is turned on and off anyway?

Why is my app freezing?
 void Init()
 {
     AVAudioSession session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();

     session.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback,
                      AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.AllowAirPlay |
                      AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.AllowBluetoothA2DP |
                      AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DuckOthers);

     AVAudioSession.Notifications.ObserveRouteChange(Session_RouteChanged);

     session.SetActive(true);

 }

 protected void Session_RouteChanged(object sender, AVAudioSessionRouteChangeEventArgs e)
 {
     AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason reason = e.Reason;

     return;
 }




Is it freezing or crashing?  Those are two different things

Freezing indefinitely

I found an answer to the problem.
When the route changed for some reason the AVAudioEngine would stop running.
As a result, my app, which was auto-calling ScheduleSegment was doing so on a stopped Engine. If I restart the Engine before performing this call, all works ok.
